# why mesos agent can not register

Tags: mesos

I start a mesos-master and mesos-agent on my virtual machine(master and agent all on the same server).

```
# mesos-master --work_dir=/opt/mesos_master
# GLOG_v=1 mesos-agent --master=127.0.0.1:5050 \
  --isolation=docker/runtime,filesystem/linux \
  --work_dir=/opt/mesos_slave --image_providers=docker
```

And I got the screen output like this

```
I0726 18:13:57.042263  8224 master.cpp:4619] Registered agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 at slave(1)@202.106.199.37:5051 (bt-199-037.bta.net.cn) with cpus(*):4; mem(*):944; disk(*):10680; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0726 18:13:57.042392  8224 coordinator.cpp:348] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE action at position 226
I0726 18:13:57.042790  8224 hierarchical.cpp:478] Added agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 (bt-199-037.bta.net.cn) with cpus(*):4; mem(*):944; disk(*):10680; ports(*):[31000-32000] (allocated: )
I0726 18:13:57.042994  8224 replica.cpp:537] Replica received write request for position 226 from (21)@202.106.199.37:5050
I0726 18:13:57.050371  8224 leveldb.cpp:341] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 7.277511ms
I0726 18:13:57.050611  8224 replica.cpp:712] Persisted action at 226
I0726 18:13:57.050882  8224 replica.cpp:691] Replica received learned notice for position 226 from @0.0.0.0:0
I0726 18:13:57.053961  8224 leveldb.cpp:341] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 3.035601ms
I0726 18:13:57.054203  8224 leveldb.cpp:399] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 167530ns
I0726 18:13:57.054226  8224 replica.cpp:712] Persisted action at 226
I0726 18:13:57.054234  8224 replica.cpp:697] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 226
I0726 18:14:46.817351  8228 master.cpp:4520] Agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 at slave(1)@202.106.199.37:5051 (bt-199-037.bta.net.cn) already registered, resending acknowledgement
E0726 18:14:50.530529  8231 process.cpp:2105] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 12: Transport endpoint is not connected
E0726 18:15:00.045917  8231 process.cpp:2105] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 13: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0726 18:15:00.045985  8226 master.cpp:1245] Agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 at slave(1)@202.106.199.37:5051 (bt-199-037.bta.net.cn) disconnected
I0726 18:15:00.046139  8226 master.cpp:2784] Disconnecting agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 at slave(1)@202.106.199.37:5051 (bt-199-037.bta.net.cn)
I0726 18:15:00.046185  8226 master.cpp:2803] Deactivating agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 at slave(1)@202.106.199.37:5051 (bt-199-037.bta.net.cn)
I0726 18:15:00.046233  8226 hierarchical.cpp:571] Agent 28354e0c-fe56-4a82-a420-98489be4519a-S2 deactivated
```

Can anybody know that why the agent can not got registered to the master?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before.  Add your local ip to /etc/mesos-master/ip  or  /etc/mesos-slave/ip

Answer (score 1):

When you see in your mesos-master log file the next line:

```
master.cpp:3216] Deactivating agent AGENT_ID at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (HOSTNAME)
```

Means that you didn't mention the mesos-agent IP address. Add as startup parameter --ip=AGENT_HOST_IP to your agent startup script or command.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell the master which network interface to listen on. Most probably—that's what your agent log hints at—it listens at `202.106.199.37:5050`.

Either explicitly tell your master to listen on `127.0.0.1` via `--ip` flag, or tell your agent where your master is (you can get this information from its log).